# Avoid to call Organization level webhook

Tags: github, webhooks, github-enterprise, github-webhook, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

Currently, we're using an organization-level generic-webhook for all our repo.

Recently we had added new repo repo. which needs to be use only repo level generic-webhook for some reason.

Is there any way, So that i can call only repo level generic-webhook and ignore organization level webhook ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to do this.  GitHub delivers a *lot* of webhook events and users generally want them delivered *right away*.  In order to make webhook delivery as speedy and efficient as possible, there aren't any filtering options on GitHub's side.  You're expected to receive all the events you're subscribed to and filter them yourself.

If you want the organization-level webhook to not operate on this particular repository, you'll need to configure your service that receives the webhook itself not to act on those messages.